# PySimpleGUI: is there any way to create a new folder from FileSaveAs?

Tags: python, directory, pysimplegui

But I would like for the user, when using a "Save As" function, to also be able to create a new folder in which to put the file.

Is there any way to do this? I've looked through the call reference and the demo programs and don't see anything. FileSaveAs  works beautifully for existing folders, but there doesn't seem to be any parameter to get it to make new folders.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sg.SaveAs()` chooser button in PySimpleGUI opens a "Save As" dialog box.  It has specific options provided for the user to create folders that are not normally shown when browsing for a file to open.

If you wish to create them for the user, you can use `os.mkdir` prior to showing the dialog.

[image]

Comment: Alas, that doesn't seem to work. I wonder if it is a difference between the linux and windows versions. I'm using linux and SaveAs seems to behave exactly the same as FileSaveAs. Could you tell me which option you are using? I don't see anything in the Call Reference which seems relevant.

Comment: Update: yes, it *is* a difference between the linux and windows versions, or at least their underlying libraries. I just tried the same code on the testbed windows laptop - Core i3, very slow indeed, which is why I don't develop on it. Oh well...

Comment: Right click, New-Folder?  Or press Control+N

Comment: I'm afraid neither of those seems to do anything...I'm trying the right click and C-n when the save as window pops up. Am I missing something. (BTW thanks for the speedy replies).